# [Derived Column [40]] Error: An error occurred while attempting to perform a type cast

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssis

i have write the date and time column query in Sql Server with IsNull condition.. i have mentioned that query in below..

i want that query is, how to write the ssis derived column .  i have written that query in ssis but some cast type error comes..

here concatenate the date and time columns.

please help me,

Sql Query ---

```
CAST(ISNULL(CONVERT(Nvarchar(10),InitialDate,101), '01/01/1900')  AS Nvarchar(10))+ ' ' + ISNULL(CONVERT(NVarChar(8),InitialTime,108), '00:00:00')   as  CourtDttm
```

SSIS Derived column

```
(DT_DBTIMESTAMP)((DT_STR,255,1252)(ISNULL(InitialDate) ? ((DT_DBTIMESTAMP)"01/01/1900") : (InitialDate)) + " " +
((DT_STR,255,1252)(ISNULL(InitialTime) ? ((DT_DBTIMESTAMP)"00 : 00 : 00") : (InitialTime))))


Errors --[Derived Column [40]] Error: An error occurred while attempting to perform a type cast.
```

Comment: My guess would be on some invalid data. You can redirect erroneous rows to some file and the check whats causing trouble.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're looking for:

```
DT_DBDATE - A date structure that consists of year, month, and day.

DT_DBTIME - A time structure that consists of hour, minute, and second.
```

If you use DT_DBTIMESTAMP, you'll have to fill in the date part like you did for InitialDate.